# Getting list indices must be integers in Django views

Tags: python, django

I'm scraping some data inside Django views.py and append them to a dictionary that looks like this:

```
movie_data = {
        'movie_details': [],
        'actor_details' : [],
        'dir_details': [],

    }
```

and then append to it like below:

```
movie_data['movie_details'].append({'title': title, 'summary': summary})
```

I defined a variable `title = movie_data['movie_details'][0]['title']` to create objects from it but I get the error below when I try to do so:

```
list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Which already is an integer, and I've tried my code outside of Django and tried to print the data using `print(movie_data['movie_details'][0]['title'])` and it worked.

Can anyone help me find where the error comes from?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your `movie_data['movie_details'][0]` is probably a list which means you can't index into it with `'title'`.

Comment: its not, and I mentioned that the movie_data['movie_details'][0] is working pretty fine outside of django.

Comment: And there is no other line of code before the failing line? The message is clear, one of the objects you assume to be a dictionary is actually a list. Try additional debugging: `print(type(movie_data))` + `print(type(movie_data['movie_details'][0]))` and see if they are both dictionaries. One of them is definitely not.